# Scope Resolution Operator in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-grant, scope-resolution

What is the significance of using `Scope Resolution Operator (::)` in `SQL SERVER`. As we all know when we are using [**`GRANT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178569.aspx) command Scope Resolution Operator will be part of syntax.

```
GRANT ALTER ON Schema :: DBO TO user_name
```

Is there any specific meaning for it or it is used just like that.

Comment: To get technical: that is not a "scope resolution operator". (That [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd206995), but is something different.) Some languages have such a general operator for identifiers, but in T-SQL, the `class::` construct is used simply as that -- to specify the class of object you're operating on. It occurs only in `GRANT`, `DENY` and `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` statements and is not generally applicable. As to why it's necessary, that's another matter. The rules for when objects of different types can share names and when they can't are a bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

refer,

> http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/09/06/186.aspx

it does not have any meaning check below query,

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

and if you execute without :: it still get executed.